Does individual differences in pain tolerance impact the pain score rating?
I have been looking at clinical studies due to self interest. In studies where the severity of pain is evaluated, a pain scale with a pain score of 0 to 10 is often used.
However, since different people would likely to have different tolerance to pain as well as difference in describing the sensations they feel, would this impact the pain score given from the patients? If so, would this cause a significant error or bias in research studies where the pain score is used as a measuring outcome?

I think the far greater problem is with the physician's perception of the patient's pain, with underestimation being a major problem.

Short answer: yes. Pain-reporting (especially on the standard 0-10 scale or Wong-Baker Faces) is subject to significant amounts of bias due to a multitude of factors.
In one study (citation below), it was found that people tend to overreport their pain levels due to:

Wanting to enhance the provider's belief and responsiveness
Increasing the likelihood of receiving pain relief
Fear of future pain or potential illness

On the other hand, people underreport pain due to:

Concerns about how their pain affects and is perceived by others
Financial concerns

***But there could be a new way to figure out severity of pain using biomarkers or brain activity (https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20230414-the-search-for-an-objective-measure-of-pain)
Boring, B. L., Walsh, K. T., Nanavaty, N., Ng, B. W., & Mathur, V. A. (2021). How and Why Patient Concerns Influence Pain Reporting: A Qualitative Analysis of Personal Accounts and Perceptions of Others' Use of Numerical Pain Scales. Frontiers in psychology, 12, 663890. https://doi.org/10.3389/fpsyg.2021.663890
